# Why do need to configure repositories for installing chrome in Fedora?

Tags: unix, fedora, repository, yum

What am I exactly doing by following instructions [here](http://www.google.com/linuxrepositories/)?

Why just

```
yum install chromium
```

not work without doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The repositories are so you can update Chrome.  The official Fedora repositories don't have Google Chrome, so Google provides a repository.

You don't have to do the command line install of the repos; you can do this instead:
http://www.google.com/chrome/eula.html?platform=linux&hl=en

Just select the RPM and by installing that RPM it gives you the repository, and if I recall correctly it installs the latest version of Chrome as well in one shot.

Edit:  Oh, and I just noticed this from the page I linked to:
Note: Installing Google Chrome will add the Google repository so your system will automatically keep Google Chrome up to date. If you don't want Google's repository, do "sudo touch /etc/default/google-chrome" before installing the package.

Comment: `The official Fedora repositories don't have Google Chrome...` Why is that?

Comment: The debian repos don't either, but the Fedora repos MIGHT have chromium-browser, which is the base of chrome and works just about the same. EDIT: Just checked, they don't.

Answer (score 0):

Fedora is very picky about what goes into the official repos, their [reasons](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Chromium) are outlined. Google Chrome is a proprietary product and bundles other proprietary software such as Adobe Flash plugin.